# group concat of fields in mongodb in aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My documents in collection,

```
{
    "_id" : "abc1",
    "Data" : {
        "Campaign Name" : "Campaign 1",
        "Ad Set Name" : "Adset 1",
        "Ad Name" : "Ad 1",
        "URL Tags" : "url tag 1"
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "abc2",
    "Data" : {
        "Campaign Name" : "Campaign 2",
        "Ad Set Name" : "Adset 1",
        "Ad Name" : "Ad 1",
        "URL Tags" : "url tag 1"
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "abc3",
    "Data" : {
        "Campaign Name" : "Campaign 2",
        "Ad Set Name" : "Adset 2",
        "Ad Name" : "Ad 2",
        "URL Tags" : "url tag 2"
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "abc4",
    "Data" : {
        "Campaign Name" : "Campaign 3",
        "Ad Set Name" : "Adset 1",
        "Ad Name" : "Ad 1",
        "URL Tags" : "url tag 1"
    }
}
```

Need something like this in output,

```
{
    "_id" : "Campaign 3",
    "total" : 60.0,
    "myField" : [ "url tag 1-Ad 1" ]
},
{
    "_id" : "Campaign 2",
    "total" : 120.0,
    "myField" : [ "url tag 1-Ad 1", "url tag 2-Ad 2" ]
},
{
    "_id" : "Campaign 1",
    "total" : 96.0,
    "myField" : [ "url tag 1-Ad 1" ]
}
```

What i have done(unsuccessfully) so far,

```
db.adsets.aggregate([
    {$group:{_id:"$Data.Campaign Name",total:{$sum:1}}},
    {$project:{_id:1,total:1,myField:{$concat:["$Data.URL Tags","-","$Data.Ad Name"]}}}
],{explain:false});
```

Currently getting this in output,

```
{
    "_id" : "Campaign 3",
    "total" : 60.0,
    "myField" : null
},
{
    "_id" : "Campaign 2",
    "total" : 120.0,
    "myField" : null
},
{
    "_id" : "Campaign 1",
    "total" : 96.0,
    "myField" : null
}
```

I don't know what i am doing wrong which is why i am getting null instead of concatenated string in myField. Please help!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please post valid JSON, this `"myField" : {url tag 1-Ad 1,url tag 2-Ad 2}` is not valid, did you perhaps mean an array like `"myField" : [ "url tag 1-Ad 1", "url tag 2-Ad 2" ]`?

Comment: Yes i need this array,
"myField" : [ "url tag 1-Ad 1", "url tag 2-Ad 2" ] 
OR
"myField" : [{ "url tag 1-Ad 1"}, {"url tag 2-Ad 2"} ]

Comment: The latter `"myField" : [{ "url tag 1-Ad 1"}, {"url tag 2-Ad 2"} ]` is invalid JSON, hope you are aware of that.

Comment: Sorry yes i know that, i was in hurry
 [ "url tag 1-Ad 1", "url tag 2-Ad 2" ]  this would be great for me

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can concatenate required values and push to an array during grouping:

```
db.adsets.aggregate([
    {$group:{
        _id:"$Data.Campaign Name",
        total : {$sum:1},
        myfield: {$push: {$concat:["$Data.URL Tags", "-", "$Data.Ad Name"]}}
        }
    }]
)
```

This should give output as you mentioned.
(As you mentioned in your question comment, myfield field will be an array as you need and not object like initial question)

If you don't want concatenated values to appear twice when same, you can use $addToSet instead of push

```
db.adsets.aggregate([
    {$group:{
        _id:"$Data.Campaign Name",
        total : {$sum:1},
        myfield: {$addToSet: {$concat:["$Data.URL Tags", "-", "$Data.Ad Name"]}}
        }
    }]
)
```

Comment: I don't want duplication in myFields, its working fine but showing duplicate values. I want distinct.

Comment: If you are referring to duplicate in array, use $addToSet instead of push